# SQL MS Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, sql-update, ms-access-2013

I have the following SQL statement:

```
UPDATE tbl_Invoices
SET tbl_Invoices.Base = tbl_Bases.BasePrice
FROM tbl_Invoices
INNER JOIN tbl_Bases ON tbl_Bases.ProductNumber  =  tbl_Invoices.ProductNumber
                     AND tbl_Bases.ChangeOrderID = tbl_Invoices.ChangeOrderID
                     AND tbl_Bases.CustomerName = 'VALEO' 
                     AND tbl_Bases.CountryCode = 'FR'
                     AND tbl_Bases.ContractYear = 0
```

Access keep telling me I have a syntax error (missing operator)

This drives me nuts. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Can you post the exact error message? And also the DDL/DML scripts for the tables? The query looks OK at first sight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot.
I still have an error as the = 'VALEO' etc... are not allowed in Join but this is working if moved to a where clause:

```
UPDATE tbl_Invoices
INNER JOIN tbl_Bases ON tbl_Bases.ProductNumber  =  tbl_Invoices.ProductNumber
                     AND tbl_Bases.ChangeOrderID = tbl_Invoices.ChangeOrderID
SET tbl_Invoices.Base = tbl_Bases.BasePrice
WHERE tbl_Bases.CustomerName = 'VALEO' 
                     AND tbl_Bases.CountryCode = 'FR'
                     AND tbl_Bases.ContractYear = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE ... FROM` doesn't exist in Access SQL, here you do it like this:

```
UPDATE tbl_Invoices
INNER JOIN tbl_Bases ON tbl_Bases.ProductNumber  =  tbl_Invoices.ProductNumber
                     AND tbl_Bases.ChangeOrderID = tbl_Invoices.ChangeOrderID
                     AND tbl_Bases.CustomerName = 'VALEO' 
                     AND tbl_Bases.CountryCode = 'FR'
                     AND tbl_Bases.ContractYear = 0
SET tbl_Invoices.Base = tbl_Bases.BasePrice
```